# Injection inside double quoted section of script element

Tags: php, xss, javascript, injection

For a test to find vulnerabilities I found the following code in a page and I am looking for ways to manipulate it:

```
<script>
    func({
     "key1": "value",
     "object": {
         "key2": "value",
         "key3": "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['param']); ?>",
         "key4": "value",
     }
    }, "string");
</script>
```

Document is UTF-8 and default parameters for htmlspecialchars are used so `&quot; &lt; &gt; &amp;` are converted but `'`, `\` and newlines are not. htmlspecialchars can cause issues inside a script tag but is it actually possible in this case to escape the double quotes and either inject executable javascript code or manipulate the object by changing or adding keys/values?

What I have tried is to make param have a `\` at the end which escapes the double quote but that just causes a SyntaxError because the line ends after it.

So other than making the entire script fail is there a way?

Comment: Maybe try this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146324/is-it-possible-to-xss-exploit-json-responses-with-proper-javascript-string-escap

Comment: This is a pure programming question and is off topic here.